# pyspark - converting string to integer results in Null values

Tags: string, pyspark, integer

A question about something seemingly simple. I have a dataframe that contains a string column with contains numbers that I want to convert in an integer. For this I have been using:

```py
withColumn("id",col("previous_id").cast(IntegerType()))
```

But this results in null values only:

| string_column | int_column |
| --- | --- |
| 575281 | Null |
| 710332 | Null |
| 700480 | Null |

Apparently I am overlooking something but not sure what. Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe the string field has trailing spaces -- try `func.trim('string_column').cast('int')`

Comment: oddly enough, even after trimming the column, the results are null: .withColumn("id",F.trim(col("previous_id")).cast(IntegerType()))

Comment: in that case, are you sure the numbers are just like you've shared in your question? does it have any commas?

Comment: I checked but no comma's what so ever. So I still need to figure out what's wrong here...

Comment: would you be able to share the screenshot of `df.show(3)` as well, considering just that column?

Comment: I could but it would look the same as above two columns... still I haven't figured out what is the cause behind this... but the purpose behind this operation: joining two tables on shared column values has been completed as string values can be joint with integer values as well. thanks!